# Clicking on Recaptcha

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

I am trying to click on a recaptcha but everything I tried resulted in the inability to identify the iframe on the site http://database.globalreporting.org/reports/51732/download-report-pdf/.  I tried finding the iframe element without switching frames, switching frames to find the element, and changing the browser to Firefox from Chrome.  I'm finally relenting an wondering if somebody here could help.

Comment: also you should be aware the `reCaptcha` is there for a reason you may still have no luck getting past it, it's very purpose is to defeat people such as yourself

Comment: The _entire point_ of a CAPTCHA is to make sure a real person is interacting with something. Clicking it with any automation tool isn't likely to be straightforward...